# Why are some of my up-voted posts not getting reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

My [daily recap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146792/mac?tab=reputation) is behaving strangely, displaying `0` for some questions in which I already gained points.

[image]

This is from example a shot from the second question with `0` points:

[image]

I already triggered a manual reputation recap, but without success. Previously I observed a similar behaviour with questions that I first deleted and then undeleted, but this is not the case for either of the two.

I'm mostly curious about what is going one, as in the past the reputation self-corrected in a few days.

Comment: Looks like you hit the 200 Rep cap for that day..

Answer (score 2):

You've really hit the daily reputation limit and in total, you've received +0 for that post

[image]

- You've received 3 upvotes, over the cap, it means that you got nothing
- After that, you've received one downvote. Your cap was at 198
- Someone upvoted you, you've received two reputation points back, which results in total of 0 earned reputation for that post